# $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] is Undefined on php over plesk

Tags: php, plesk

I am running a PHP script over PLESK that runs PHP codes via **fastcgi to php** feature.

everything works well but when I want to get USER IP address via this code

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
```

I encounter this error message :

```
Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_ADDR
```

It seems server variables are not available in PHP that runs over PLESK CGI

Please help me, if I want to get user IPs via php code, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user's IP is in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, not `SERVER_ADDR`.